# How to upload an image to cloudant database?

Tags: image, upload, attachment, cloudant

I am trying to upload an image to cloudant database, using the cloudant client - 2.0.0

Here's my code looks like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, Exception
{

    try
    {
        CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account("uri").username(user).password(password).build();
        System.out.println("Server Version: " + client.serverVersion());

        Database db = client.database("rss_news", false);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("_attachments", new Attachment(encodeFileToBase64Binary("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg"), "image/jpeg"));
        obj.put("name", "bhanwar");
        db.save(obj);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// A Java type that can be serialized to JSON

private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName) throws IOException
{

    File file = new File(fileName);
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    System.out.println(bytes.length);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);
    System.out.println("---encodedString---" + encodedString);
    return encodedString;
}

private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0)
    {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length)
    {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

But this does not work.

The object gets created on the cloudant db, but the schema does not look like "_attachments" as mentioned in the doc.

Also, the attributes like length and revops are 0.

Please suggest.